# is possible open 2 sqlite database in the same program Xcode

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that uses sqlite. I read tables from sqlite file that I have in 'resource'. I tried to read tables from another sqlite file, but the program failed with following error

> for2012-04-10 14:12:14.331 SQL[1804:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>
> reason: 'Could 
>   not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle 
>   (loaded)' with name 'RootViewController''

If I don't read the first sqlite file, I can read the second. If I don't read the second, I can read the first. But can't read together.

Is not possible read two sqlite file in the same program?

Comment: Yes it is possible, the error say that you've a problem with your xib file. Are you deleting a RootViewController.xib when you load the second database?

Comment: Right, the question has nothing to do with SQLite. The problem is with the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use multiple SQLite files in a project. In case they are in your documents directory, then you may select any one of them as :

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSString* sqlfilePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file1.sqlite"]; 

BOOL file1Exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlfilePath];

NSString* sqlfilePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file2.sqlite"]; 

BOOL file2Exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlfilePath];


if(file1)
{
     // do necessary operations here
} 

else if (file2)
{
     // do necessary operations here
}
```

However, in your case i think `RootViewController` is the cause of the issue and not SQLlite files.